# How add minutes to timestamp variable in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql, timestamp

I am trying to add 30 minutes to a timestamp variable in PL/SQL  as following:

```
DECLARE
    l_start_timestamp timestamp;
    l_end_timestamp timestamp;
    rnk number;
     BEGIN
            l_start_timestamp := to_timestamp('&start_time', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
            l_end_timestamp := to_timestamp('&end_time', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
     .........................
    ..........................
    END;
    /
```

Getting below error:

```
Enter value for start_time: 25-03-2016 00:00:00
old  23:        l_start_timestamp := to_timestamp('&start_time', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
new  23:        l_start_timestamp := to_timestamp('25-03-2016 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
Enter value for end_time: 26-03-2016 00:00:00
old  24:        l_end_timestamp := to_timestamp('&end_time', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
new  24:        l_end_timestamp := to_timestamp('26-03-2016 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
        l_start_timestamp := to_timestamp('25-03-2016 00:00:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '00:30' HOUR TO MINUTE;
                                                                                            *
ERROR at line 23:
ORA-06550: line 23, column 86:
PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal
```

Kindly, help me how to do this.

Thanks in Advance.!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try just adding minutes instead of converting hours to minutes.

```
DECLARE
  l_start_timestamp timestamp;
  l_end_timestamp timestamp;
  rnk number;
BEGIN
  l_start_timestamp := to_timestamp('&start_time', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE;
  l_end_timestamp := to_timestamp('&end_time', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have run into an Oracle bug (at least in 11gR2).

The interval statement is perfectly valid:

```
SQL> select date'2016-03-29' + interval '01:30' hour to minute from dual;

DATE'2016-03-29'+IN
-------------------
2016-03-29 01:30:00
```

However it doesn't work in PL/SQL context event it should:

```
declare
  v_date date := date'2016-03-29' + interval '01:30' hour to minute;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(v_date);
end;
/

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 37:
PLS-00166: bad format for date, time, timestamp or interval literal
```

Possible workarounds:

```
declare
  v_date date := date'2016-03-29' + interval '1' hour + interval '30' minute;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line(v_date);
end;
/

2016-03-29 01:30:00

declare
  v_date date;
begin
  select date'2016-03-29' + interval '01:30' hour to minute
    into v_date
    from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(v_date);
end;
/

2016-03-29 01:30:00
```